# NetSuite: how to hide a column on accounts page?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I need to hide Balance and Foreign currency balance columns on accounts page (Setup>Accounting>Charts of Accounts) for any other roles in this company besides the administrator.
I tried to create User Event Script for Account record type, I thought it could be used to zero out the balance fields get loaded. But my script wont get loaded until I edit an account. But I need my script to get loaded on Accounts list page. Please help!

Comment: for example, administrator should see all the data in column "Balance"; however, the guy from accountant department or marketing department cannot see "Balance" column. 
I have asked the netsuite support team and they just suck as usual. and I been got a lot help from stackoverflow, and any advice at this moment is much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

The Chart Of Accounts list page is not scriptable with SuiteScript. Your best bet is to create a Saved Search where you filter out the accounts you don't want the other roles to see and grant them access to the Saved Search but not the Chart Of Accounts list.

Comment: Setting the filter is also a way; will it full-fill my requirements?
Do I still need the script or is there anything I can change directly in NetSuite Platform?
Thanks for the reply~

Comment: I guess I can create a Saved Search directly in NetSuite; can you please show me more details about it? thank you very much for the help!